# Extract path without filename using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've exactly the string below. Using Regex how can I extract only the path?

```
"C:\Python34\py.exe" "%1" %*
```

I already tried these patterns unsuccessfully:

> ([a-zA-Z]*:[\[a-zA-Z0-9 .]*]*)

It gives me the whole path `C:\Python34\py.exe`

> ^[^ \t]+[ \t]+(.*)$

It gives me the whole string `"C:\Python34\py.exe" "%1" %*`

**EDIT**

I know the options from System.IO namespace. But there's a string coming and I need to extract the path from it-> `"C:\Python34\py.exe" "%1" %*`
The string containing the path could be not regular as I showed.

Comment: is the directory always in quotes like in the example? ("")

Comment: OP...what about just first extracting the quoted path? I've updated my answer for if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could generalize it to find just enough to distinguish it
from the other quoted values.

This requires at least a `\` and `file.ext` in the quoted string.

```
 "
 # @"""([^""]*)\\([^""\\]+(?:\.[^"".\\]+))"""

 (                    # (1 start), Path
      [^"]* 
 )                    # (1 end)
 \\ 
 (                    # (2 start), File name
      [^"\\]+ 
      (?:
           \.
           [^".\\]+ 
      )
 )                    # (2 end)
 "
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 22 ) 
"C:\Python34\py.exe.d"  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 11 ) 
C:\Python34  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 13 , len 8 ) 
py.exe.d
```

Comment: Better answer so far! tks

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Regex you should use the static methods available in the [`System.IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

If you want the path without the filename you can do this:

```
string myFullPath = @"C:\Python34\py.exe";
string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(myFullPath);
//pathOnly will be "C:\Python34"
```

**EDIT**:  Since you're going to have arguments after the path we can first get the whatever is the first quoted substring:

```
Regex quotedPattern = new Regex("([\"'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1");
Match matches = quotedPattern.Match(myFullPath);
if(matches.Groups.Count > 0)
{
     pathOnly = matches.Captures[0].Value;
     pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathOnly);
}
```

Regex Test:  [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b%22%27%5d)(%3f%3a(%3f%3d(%5c%5c%3f))%5c2.)*%3f%5c1&i=%22C%3a%5cPython34%5cpy.exe%22+%22%251%22+%25*)

Comment: I know this option. But there's a string coming and I need to extract the path from it-> "C:\Python34\py.exe" "%1" %*

Comment: Why don't you just split on whitespace then?  Then you'll have the path separate from the arguments.

Comment: Because I can't guarantee it'll always be a regular string as I showed.

Comment: @Gandarez what are the irregular cases possible?

Comment: posibles are undetermined, however could be "C:\Python34\py.exe" "%1" %* or "C:\Python34\py.exe""%1"%* or "C:\Python34\py.exe%1%* or etc..

Comment: @JNYRanger: Splitting on whitespace could go wrong if the path itself contains whitespace. In particular, the quotation marks in the full invocation string are supposed to override separation by whitespace.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Good point.   OP can potentially extract the whole file path by extracting whatever is quoted (assuming it's always quoted) and then use the `Path.GetDirectoryName` method, and use the remainder of the non-quoted path as the args

Comment: Didn't work. Those 2 groups are similar and return "C:\Python34\py.exe" "%1"

Comment: @Gandarez I updated the regex to make sure it only pulls the first set of quotes.  Note that the index changed on the groups that are matched in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

In your case using `Path.GetDirectoryName` on your input directly, throw exception. You may try this non-regex approach using combination of `Split`, `Trim` and `GetDirectoryName`:

```
string value = "\"C:\\Python34\\py.exe\" \"%1\" %*";

var result = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(value.Split(' ').First().Trim('\"'));
//result: C:\Python34
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `Path.GetDirectoryName` and a simple `Substring`:

```
string value = "\"C:\\Python34\\py.exe\" \"%1\" %*";
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(value.Substring(1, value.IndexOf("\"", 2)-1));
```

[see fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O4uDFi)